# Tinted Shadow Blender 4.0 Agx

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color-management

[image]
Hi! I need some help people, I've been wanting to use 4.0 Beta for its AGX color space since it makes the textures we use at work be super detailed and true to reference, buuuut we've been experiencing tinted shadows and almost an emissive effect when using AgX Base sRGB for textures and AgX scene color space. I use bearly any light in the scene the color just light up and saturates as if the emission was turned on. If the texture is loaded en sRGB its super desaturated and with less detail.
The material is standard, even using a Diffuse BSDF, no SSS or anything, default render settings and only an HDRI. Does anyone have a clue what I'm missing? Maybe it's a wrong combination of settings or something? This problem is consistent in the Windows and mac versions. If I'm stupid just tell me upfront, my mom already agrees.

files: [https://we.tl/t-HBymD5iLFf](https://files:%20https://we.tl/t-HBymD5iLFf)

Comment: I don't think you'll find many people here using Blender 4 yet as it's not officially released until next month. It might be worth submitting a bug report via Blender's Help Submit a Bug menu and see what the response is.